# Infinite number of square roots of a complex matrix (explanation)

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

On a previous post :

[Infinite number of square roots of a complex matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573944/infinite-number-of-square-roots-of-a-complex-matrix)

I asked given $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ diagonalizable that has a non-zero eigenvalue with a multiplicity greater than 2 whether we could find an infinite number of **diagonalizable** matrices $M$ such as $M^2=A$.

The answer I had was :

[image]

Which is really helpful. But I have no clue why the matrix $B$ is diagonalizable, for me $B$ as presented here is triangularizable.

Could anyone help me further please?

Comment: In $2$ space, all reflections have square $I$, and are diagonalizable.  There are uncountably many of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** An upper triangular matrix with *different* diagonal entries is always diagonalizable (with the same diagonal), as it has $n$ different eigenvalues, hence an eigenbasis (or, prove by using elementary basis transformations).

In particular, $\pmatrix{1&z\\0&-1}$ is similar to $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I'm not sure on the method though, should I come back to the determinant?

Comment: Maybe the simplest is to use the characteristic polynomial: its roots are the eigenvalues.. And/or find the specific basis transformation for the $2\times 2$ example.

Comment: With $\det(I_nX-A)$ I have found the expression of the characteristic polynomial. How do I conclude please?

Comment: I don't necessarily have $n$ different eigenvalues

Comment: $A-Ix$ is an upper triangular matrix with polynomial entries, its determinant is simply the product of the diagonal elements $(a_{ii}-x)$. The roots of this polynomial are exactly $a_{ii}$. Also, its roots are exactly the eigenvalues. So, $a_{11},\dots, a_{nn}$ are $n$ different eigenvalues, there belong eigenvectors to them, which must be linearly independent.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I agree on that point. But $a_{33},a_{44},...,a_{nn}$ are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: Having $n$ different diagonal entries is the hypothesis of my general statement. Your question only concerns diagonalizability of $\pmatrix{1&z\\0 & -1}$, doesn't it?

Comment: No my question was about $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & z \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix} \bigoplus \text{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_3},...\sqrt{\lambda_n})$

Comment: Ok, but its other part is already a diagonal..

Comment: So if I have $\sqrt{\lambda_1}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & z \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix} \bigoplus \text{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_3},...\sqrt{\lambda_n})$ then I can diagonalize that into $\text{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},-\sqrt{\lambda_1},\sqrt{\lambda_3},...\sqrt{\lambda_n})$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Note also that $\oplus$ is just forming block matrix $\pmatrix{\sqrt{\lambda_1} &\sqrt{\lambda_1}z\\ & -\sqrt{\lambda_1}\\ && \sqrt{\lambda_3}\\ &&& \ddots}$.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking that much questions. My point is, what allows me to diagonalize the blocks? What are the arguments to do as I said in the previous comment?

Comment: Look, if you find the basis transformation for the $2\times 2$ case, you will probably see that exactly the same basis transformation will work on the bigger matrix as well (we simply don't touch basis vectors $e_3,e_4,\dots$, as they are already eigenvectors -- meaning that their corresponding column in the matrix only contains nonzero on the diagonal).

Comment: It is crystal clear. Sorry for your time.

Comment: You're welcome.